# Deploying a Production Rails app on an Intranet/LAN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

My usual deploy setup consists of ubuntu/postgresql/nginx/unicorn running on a vps, I need to set up an app that will only be run on an intranet/LAN(on ubuntu).
Having never done this before what are the differences from a usual vps deployment?

Do I only need to change the `server_name` in my nginx.conf from;

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com ;
  root /home/deployer/example/current/public;
  }
```

to `server_name localhost;`?

Comment: no, I'd like someone to answer who has done this before

Comment: seems like it's worth trying it first though...?  what you have presently might work and then this question is meaningless

Comment: Well I can't try it out, so do you know the answer?

Comment: so you want to make it available through it's IP in the LAN? normaly, you would configure your nameserver to give that server an internal name and use that to configure your server.

Answer (score 0):

The server name will only be useful if your internal DNS server is configured to point at your web server's IP address. That way other computers on the LAN can find it by its name. If you don't want to get in to configuring an internal DNS, just set the server_name to your web server's IP address and other computers can use the IP to connect to it.

- Here's an article about setting nginx in a LAN: http://zaiste.net/2013/03/serving_apps_locally_with_nginx_and_pretty_domains/
- Here's an answer about internal DNS: https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network